# Order of checkbox and label in right-to-left direction

Tags: html, css

[HTML offers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.2) the `dir` option where i can put the direction of the elements to "right-to-left".

When i add this attribute to my `body`, everything works fine, except of the order of the label-input fields.

I place the input before the label like this:

```
<input id="input_id" type="radio" name="radio_button">
<label for="input_id">Radio Button text</label>
```

I understand that the dir attribute "just" changes the direction of the characters. But what is an easy way to reorder the input/label pair?

[Demo via JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ruv5w5zo/)

Comment: I just don't get what you're looking for. The order of those two inline-level elements has been changed already by `dir="rtl"` attribute/value. If you don't want that, why do you change the direction of contents? What should the output look like?

Comment: Hmm, i was blind. I'm using Angular, it seems like inside ng-repeat the order didn't change. In "pure" HTML it does.

Comment: The `dir` attribute does not “just” change the direction of characters; in fact, it does not affect it all *except* when characters with neutral directionality intervene. But it does set the overall layout direction. So what are you using it for if not that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your questions really is how to control the order of label and input field you need to add styling rules for this:

```
label{float:right;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruv5w5zo/3/

Comment: Then the question is: what's the reason to alter direction of content? The question seems vague to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <input id="input_id" type="radio" name="radio_button"/>
    <label for="input_id">Radio Button</label>
</div>

input{

    float:left;
}
```

link for FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/ruv5w5zo/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following code

```css
div{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="tesone"/>
    <label for="tesone">اهلا وسهلا</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following code if instead of "My Label" you write "برچسب من" the order changes automatically and no need to change the order manually using CSS:

```
<label dir="auto">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>My Label</span>
</label>
```